Spring WebFlux and Thymeleaf do not seen to be properly working together
I have a REST API developed in Java using Spring WebFlux, and I want to add a simple web interface (login and registration form), so that when you log in you get a Java Web Token, which allows you to use the API operations.
However, I have created both views and they don't seem to load correctly, getting the following error message:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not resolve view with name 'login'. at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.ViewResolutionResultHandler.lambda$resolveViews$3(ViewResolutionResultHandler.java:275) \~\[spring-webflux-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10\] Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: Error has been observed at the following site(s):
\*\__checkpoint Ôçó Handler es.uca.api4cep.controllers.WebController#loginPage() \[DispatcherHandler\] \*\__checkpoint Ôçó es.uca.api4cep.security.JwtFilter \[DefaultWebFilterChain\] \*\__checkpoint Ôçó org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.AuthorizationWebFilter \[DefaultWebFilterChain\] \*\__checkpoint Ôçó org.springframework.security.web.server.authorization.ExceptionTranslationWebFilter \[DefaultWebFilterChain\] \*\__checkpoint Ôçó org.springframework.security.web.server.savedrequest.ServerRequestCacheWebFilter \[DefaultWebFilterChain\] \*\__checkpoint Ôçó org.springframework.security.web.server.context.SecurityContextServerWebExchangeWebFilter \[DefaultWebFilterChain\] \*\__checkpoint Ôçó org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ReactorContextWebFilter \[DefaultWebFilterChain\] \*\__checkpoint Ôçó org.springframework.security.web.server.transport.HttpsRedirectWebFilter \[DefaultWebFilterChain\] \*\__checkpoint Ôçó org.springframework.security.web.server.header.HttpHeaderWriterWebFilter \[DefaultWebFilterChain\] \*\__checkpoint Ôçó es.uca.api4cep.security.JwtFilter \[DefaultWebFilterChain\] \*\__checkpoint Ôçó org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity$ServerWebExchangeReactorContextWebFilter \[DefaultWebFilterChain\] \*\__checkpoint Ôçó org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy \[DefaultWebFilterChain\] \*\__checkpoint Ôçó HTTP GET "/" \[ExceptionHandlingWebHandler\] Original Stack Trace: at org.springframework.web.reactive.result.view.ViewResolutionResultHandler.lambda$resolveViews$3(ViewResolutionResultHandler.java:275) \~\[spring-webflux-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2097) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:118) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:241) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:144) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2571) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2367) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2241) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:294) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:188) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2571) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onSubscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:135) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:193) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:63) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:241) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onComplete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:204) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:189) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.complete(Operators.java:137) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoZip.subscribe(MonoZip.java:121) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4568) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.subscribeNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:265) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:51) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:259) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:865) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2571) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.request(MonoPeekTerminal.java:139) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2367) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2241) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:152) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4568) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:207) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:335) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerComplete(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:275) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onComplete(FluxConcatMap.java:889) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onComplete(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:241) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:357) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:294) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:337) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.request(FluxPeek.java:138) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2331) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:339) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2367) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2241) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4568) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:82) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onComplete(MonoPeekTerminal.java:299) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:155) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:122) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.innerNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:259) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:865) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:158) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:122) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:82) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:113) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:639) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:592) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(FluxFlatMap.java:349) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2331) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.request(FluxPeekFuseable.java:783) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.request(FluxMap.java:164) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.request(MonoFlatMap.java:194) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.request(Operators.java:2331) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:339) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.request(MonoNext.java:108) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.request(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:98) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.request(FluxFilter.java:186) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2367) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2241) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilter.java:85) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2051) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoNext.java:70) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:164) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:201) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:83) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:76) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:53) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:165) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2097) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:134) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:166) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:275) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1866) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.signalCached(MonoCacheTime.java:337) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCacheTime$CoordinatorSubscriber.onNext(MonoCacheTime.java:354) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPublishOn$PublishOnSubscriber.run(MonoPublishOn.java:181) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) \~\[reactor-core-3.6.7.jar:3.6.7\] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642) \~\[na:na\] at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) \~\[na:na\]

The views are located in src/main/resources/templates and are the following:
login.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form th:action="@{/auth/login}" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username or Email:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <a href="/register">Create an Account</a>
</body>
</html>


register.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Register</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Create an Account</h2>
    <form th:action="@{/auth/create}" method="post">
        <div>
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <a href="/">Login</a>
</body>
</html>

The controller that handles these view is:
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class WebController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String registerPage() {
        return "register";
    }
}

I have tried many things but have not achieved anything.
Thymeleaf seems to be correctly imported and configured.
My Pom.xml contains:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

and my application.properties has:
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

If anyone knows why I am not able to render the views correctly, please let me know.

Please don't use quotes to format stacktraces please format it with regular code tags. That way it is actually readable.

Thank you for your recommendation. I've edited the post.

That is not formatted, that is one big line. Just copy/paste the stacktrace as is, with multiple lines etc. Then wrap that in code tags. One thing I noticed ditch the spring.thymeleaf properties, those are the defaults already.
